# Is there a way to rotate an Image without loading into Memory in Android?

Tags: android, rotation, out-of-memory

Is there a way to read the orientation and rotate if needed?

I want the user to take a picture by the camera. 
After that I check if the orientation is portrait. If not, rotate the Image and save it in internal storage for later use. (I have to store it in internal storage, for the case that the user deletes the image in gallery).

So here is my way to rotate the image:

```
int orientation = 0;
try {
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(orientation);
Bitmap decodeFile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decodeFile,0,0,decodeFile.getWidth(),decodeFile.getHeight(),matrix,true);
FileOutputStream out = null;

File pictureDir = new File(getFilesDir() + "/images/");
randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
File file = new File(pictureDir.getAbsolutePath(), randomUUID + ".jpg");


try {
    imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,out);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

At line `Bitmap decodeFile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath)`, I get on old devices an OOM.
I tried to use `BitmapFactory.Options` and `inJustDecodeBounds=true` but the `rotatedImage` is null.

So how to just read the orientation and rotate the image while saving it in internal storage?

I've read many posts in stackoverflow but none of them had the same case.

Is it possible without loading it in memory?

Thank you for any help!

Kind Regards,
raymondis